# Avoid two-phase commits in a event sourced application saving BLOB data

Tags: blob, domain-driven-design

Let's assume we have an Aggregate `User` which has a `UserPortraitImage` and a `Contract` as a PDF file. I want to store files in a dedicated document-based store and just hold process-relevant data in the event (with a link to the BLOB data).

But how do I avoid a two-phase commit when I have to store the files and store the new event?

At first I'd store the documents and then the event; if the first transaction fails it doesn't matter, the command failed. If the second transaction fails it also doesn't matter even if we generated some dead files in the store, the command fails; we could even apply a rollback.
But could there be an additional problem?

The next question is how to design the aggregate and the event. If the aggregate only holds a reference to the BLOB storage, what is the process after a `SignUp` command got called?

`SignUpCommand` ==> Store documents (`UserPortraitImage` and `Contract`) ==> Create new `User` aggregate with the given BLOB storage references and store it?

Is there a better design which unburdens the aggregate of knowing that BLOB data is saved in another store? And who is responsible for storing BLOB data and forwarding the reference to the aggregate?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are working with something analogous to an AtomPub [media-entry/media-link-entry](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023#section-4.3) pair.  The blob is going into your data store, the meta data gets copied into the aggregate history

> But how do I avoid a two-phase commit when I have to store the files and store the new event?

In practice, you probably don't.

That is to say, if the blob store and the aggregate store happen to be the same database, then you can update both in the same transaction.  That couples the two stores, and adds some pretty strong constraints to your choice of storage, but it is doable.

Another possibility is that you accept that the two changes that you are making are isolated from one another, and therefore that for some period of time the two stores are not consistent with each other.

In this second case, [the saga pattern](http://vasters.com/archive/Sagas.html) is what you are looking for, and it is exactly what you describe; you pair the first action with a compensating action to take if the second action fails.  So "manual" rollback.

Or not - in a sense, the git object database uses a two phase commit; an object gets copied into the object store, and then the trees get updated, and then the commit... garbage collection comes along later to discard the objects that you don't need.

> who is responsible for storing BLOB data and forwarding the reference to the aggregate?

Well, ultimately it is an infrastructure concern; does your model actually need to interact with the document, or is it just carrying a [claim check](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html) that can be redeemed later?

Comment: If I use a Saga, where do I keep the BLOB data in the meantime? How would the process look like?

Answer (score 1):

> At first I'd store the documents and then the event; if the first
>   transaction fails it doesn't matter, the command failed. If the second
>   transaction fails it also doesn't matter even if we generated some
>   dead files in the store, the command fails; we could even apply a
>   rollback. But could there be an additional problem?

Not that I can think of, aside from wasted disk space. That's what I typically do when I want to avoid distributed transactions or when they're not available across the two types of data stores. Oftentimes, one of the two operations is less important and you can afford to let it complete even if the master operation fails later.

Cleaning up botched attempts can be done during exception handling, as an out-of-band process or as part of a Saga as @VoiceOfUnreason explained.

> SignUpCommand ==> Store documents (UserPortraitImage and Contract) ==>
>   Create new User aggregate with the given BLOB storage references and
>   store it?

Yes. Usually the Application layer component (Command handler in your case) acts as a coordinator betweeen the different data stores and gets back all it needs to know from one store before talking to the other or to the Domain.